# AWS Data Transfer costs: Small amounts in many regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-transfer, billing

What could be the reason(s) of AWS Data Transfer costs on screen shots below? We are using Ireland as a region but as you can see there are data transfers to different regions. Any idea or clue that might cause these data transfers?

[image: aws data transfer ss 1]

[image: aws data transfer ss 2]

Comment: You should probably ask AWS support. Are you using CloudFront? Or maybe API Gateway with caching enabled? AWS Global Accelerator?

Comment: I am not using api gateway and global accelerator but I am using cloudfront. I will look into cloudfront, it might be the cause

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I also have similar Data Transfer costs, even to regions I never touch (eg Osaka-Local).

However, there are all small amounts like yours and are listed as $0.00 cost.

I wonder if it's caused by console activity such as the Amazon S3 management console, which checks for buckets in every region?

Anyway, given that the cost is zero, it's not something that's particularly annoying aside from adding clutter to the billing dashboard.